# Apache Kafka brokers not sending metrics to Confluent Control Panel

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have deployed a 5 brokers Apache Kafka cluster with the image confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka and a Confluent Control Panel container with the confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center image, seeking the following instructions https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/docs/quickstart.html#getting-started-with-docker-client

I activated the metrics supports as follow in each node and I have restarted them:

```
##################### Confluent Metrics Reporter #######################
# Confluent Control Center and Confluent Auto Data Balancer integration
#
# Uncomment the following lines to publish monitoring data for
# Confluent Control Center and Confluent Auto Data Balancer
# If you are using a dedicated metrics cluster, also adjust the settings
# to point to your metrics kakfa cluster.
metric.reporters=io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
confluent.metrics.reporter.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
#
# Uncomment the following line if the metrics cluster has a single broker
#confluent.metrics.reporter.topic.replicas=1

##################### Confluent Proactive Support ######################
# If set to true, and confluent-support-metrics package is installed
# then the feature to collect and report support metrics
# ("Metrics") is enabled.  If set to false, the feature is disabled.
#
confluent.support.metrics.enable=true
```

But:

- I'm getting a metric.reporters = [] in the KafkaConfig log section.
- I'm getting a this WARN in the Confluent Control Center log:

  [2018-06-19 16:56:35,739] WARN broker=1008 is not instrumented with ConfluentMetricsReporter (io.confluent.controlcenter.healthcheck.HealthCheck)

  [2018-06-19 16:56:35,739] WARN broker=1009 is not instrumented with ConfluentMetricsReporter (io.confluent.controlcenter.healthcheck.HealthCheck)

  [2018-06-19 16:56:35,739] WARN broker=1006 is not instrumented with ConfluentMetricsReporter (io.confluent.controlcenter.healthcheck.HealthCheck)

  [2018-06-19 16:56:35,739] WARN broker=1010 is not instrumented with ConfluentMetricsReporter (io.confluent.controlcenter.healthcheck.HealthCheck)

  [2018-06-19 16:56:35,739] WARN broker=1007 is not instrumented with ConfluentMetricsReporter (io.confluent.controlcenter.healthcheck.HealthCheck)

Obviously, I'm getting the Rocket Image

[image]

I have followed the following instructions but nothing.

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/control-center/docs/installation/troubleshooting.html
- https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/metrics-reporter/metrics-reporter.html

This is the Docker command I use to run the Apache Kafka container:

```
docker run -d --net=confluent  --name=kafka1 -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper1:2181 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092 confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka
```

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

I'll point out the obvious.

Every broker needs that property file configured, not just one.

You need to restart Kafka after every change to that file. Since you're using Docker, you need to be respectful about not deleting your Kafka topic data (for example, use a volume mount)

You need to put a comma separated list of all five bootstrap servers on the line for the metrics reporter, not only localhost

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time :) I have set this in each server.properties broker: confluent.metrics.reporter.bootstrap.servers=kafka1:9092,kafka2:9092,kafka3:9092,kafka4:9092,kafka5:9092 But I'm getting metric.reporters = [] again in each broker log. Also, I'm getting the WARN of: [2018-06-20 09:41:30,269] WARN broker=1010 is not instrumented with ConfluentMetricsReporter (io.confluent.controlcenter.healthcheck.HealthCheck) Best regards

Comment: How are you putting that property file into the container?

Comment: For example, in the quickstart, the environment variables of the container are how you set those properties, not using a volume mounted file. https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/docs/quickstart.html

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but why is important to use volumes for metrics?

Comment: It's not. It's important for data persistence. Otherwise, you restart the container (for example Kafka process stops), you immediately lose data. That's why people don't typically run stateful applications as containers

Comment: But I guess that I have to be able to see the metrics that are produced right now, isn't it?

Comment: Only if you're not getting errors... It's not clear how you're putting that server properties file into the containers

Comment: My main concern is why I follow the steps and the metric.reporters = [] array is always empty in the KafkaConfig section. It must be something like metric.reporters = [io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter]

Comment: The steps you are following are not for the Docker containers. Again, I cannot tell how you are getting that property file into the container, but I suggest you `docker exec` into one, and then verify that the properties are properly set

Comment: Could you explain your fix a little more, please? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to explain how to attach to a docker process here in the comments. Look at the comment I provided previous pointing to the Docker quickstart pages... Please edit your question to include every one of your Docker run commands. If you have a docker compose file, then add that too